# Image not visible while exporting using Stringbuilder

Tags: html, asp.net, export, stringbuilder

Hi  I am trying to get an image in an export to word.
I designed in html using string builder but i am not getting image.
 My code is below. var image contains say 'Penguin.jpg'

```
 StringBuilder head = new StringBuilder();
                head.Append(@"<img src='"+Server.MapPath("")+"/img/"+image+"' alt='sdsdsd' height='42' width='42' />");
 hdnOrg.Value = head.ToString();
```

How can i correct problem?

Comment: Server.MapPath is for a physical location on the server (`C:\...`) which you cannot use as an image source. You need a URL, relative or absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign the `html` to `hidden field` that is not the correct way, use `div` instead. You can assign html to InnerHtml of div. Do not forget to make div runat="server" so that you can access it in code behind. You can use also use `Label` or `Panel`  etc as well instead of div.

**Html**

```
<div id="divForImg" runat="server" ></div>
```

**Code behind**

```
divForImg.InnerHtml = head.ToString();
```

If you want to reach the root path for path then you can use `/` forward slash and you do not need physical path rather virtual path so do not use `Server.MapPath`

```
head.Append(@"<img src='/img/" + image+  "' alt='sdsdsd' height='42' width='42' />");
```

As an additional note, using `StringBulider` here does not make much sense here as you have only one Append call and doing `string` concatenation on to make the path.

Comment: Is My path has any problem?

Comment: But i Use this Hidden Value set in master page for export to word.

Comment: Hidden field are not shown, if you want to show then you have to use something like div. To check if you have correct path, then check the generated html.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the the image url in the wrong way.

Server.MapPath("") is not supposed to be executed like that, with no params.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue

```
 strHTMLBuilder.Append(@"<img src='file://C:\Location\img.PNG'>");
```